# Why is "wry humor" more evidently used than "analogy" in this sentence?

Tags: rhetoric, rhetorical-devices

The question is from the English portion of a particular test, asking for the rhetoric strategy used in this quotation:

> I love Henry, but I cannot like him; and as for taking his arm, I should as soon think of taking the arm of an elm-tree.

Some definitions:

> **Wry humor**-form of subtle often dark humor that is frequently based on wordplay (punning), irony, or sarcasm.
>     **Analogy**-comparison (finding similarity) between two objects. (I would like to add that it is used for the purpose of illustrating something, or giving a better understanding of them)

Now, the canonical answer to this multiple choice question is wry humor. The explanation my book give is that "arm" has a double meaning, referring to both the person's arm and that of a tree.

Here is how the official explanation confuses me: it states that by punning, the author conveys that person's aloofness and lack of warmth.

Just this and that the arm of a elm tree is use to illustrate the aloofness of this person is enough to make analogy a correct answer. My question is why not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's Lit Crit

Comment: It can't be lit-crit.  I understood it.

Comment: I think it's actually sarcasm, not punning. It's using an unrealistic comparison to make its point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that there's a similarity between Henry's arm and the elm tree's arm.  In fact, that similarity is the reason that the elm tree's branch can be called an arm, and that in turn, allows the narrator to use "taking an arm" to compare doing so with Henry and the elm.  But the point of the statement is that Henry as a person is as inviting as a tree.  Taking the arm of a person is an act of companionship, but grasping a tree branch is not at all analogous.  It's the opposite, so it's a dark statement indeed that Henry is as companionable as a tree.